# XMLHttpRequest cannot load error in angularjs 2

Tags: angular, http

I am trying to call within Angularjs.
Following is the code

```
public GetVisa(): Observable<Response> {
    var origin = 'https://www.djbvisas.com/api/token/india/india/business/';

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(origin, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 204) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return response.json();
            }
        });

}
```

But it is giving me the error XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.djbvisas.com/api/token/india/india/business/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.djbvisas.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
Plz help

Comment: Does this origin domain support CORS?

Comment: actually i don't know.

Comment: Then, you already have the Answer!

Comment: can i bypass it anyhow?

Comment: You can get this Chrome plugin to bypass it locally

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: Thanks @Nehal will try